# IF series A contains values of series B THEN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

I have two Series in pandas - python:

```
A = pd.Series (["W1","W2","W3","W4"])
B = pd.Series (["W1","W2","W3"])
```

and a while loop iterates the Series A:

```
while j < len(A):
```

Now I want some kind of IF statement, when the actual value j in A is as well in the Series B, then print "It its in B":

```
IF A[j] == B: 
   print("It its in B")
```

I am really trying since some hours with A.isin() but I am not successful.

Thanks for the upcoming support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explicit Python-level loop is usually not recommended with Pandas. More idiomatic would be to use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with Boolean indexing:

```
print(A[A.isin(B)])

0    W1
1    W2
2    W3
dtype: object
```

Then iterate, if necessary;

```
res = A[A.isin(B)]
for val in res.values:
    print(f'{val} is in B')
```

You *could* use an explicit `for` loop with an `if` statement in each loop. With this method it's advisable to use `set` for O(1) lookup:

```
B_set = set(B)
for i in range(len(A)):
    val = A.iat[i]
    if val in B_set:
        print(f'{val} is in B')

W1 is in B
W2 is in B
W3 is in B
```